# CUPS and Foomatic fail with "Cannot allocate memory" on Arch Linux ARM

Tags: linux, printing, arch-linux, cups, alarm

I'm trying to print to my Brother MFC-7820N via network printing on a Pogoplug with Arch Linux ARM installed on it. I'm using the BRScript3 CUPS driver that came in the distribution. When I try to print at 300 dpi, the print job processes forever but never returns an error or prints. When I switch to 600 dpi, the printer prints an error message and the CUPS log says this:

```
W [26/Nov/2013:22:00:06 -0600] [cups-driverd] Unable to execute "/usr/lib/cups/driver/foomatic": Cannot allocate memory
W [26/Nov/2013:22:00:06 -0600] [cups-driverd] Unable to execute "/usr/lib/cups/driver/gutenprint.5.2": Cannot allocate memory
```

The print job status within the CUPS web interface is "Filter failed."

Given that my system is a little embedded device, I might suspect the system doesn't have enough RAM to do the job, but about half the system memory (at least 55MB and sometimes quite a bit more) is free. Is it really a RAM issue? Is there any way to get around this issue? I don't have a swap drive since I'm running the system off of a USB flash drive.

**UPDATE**: The output of *free* is:

```
[root@alarm ~]# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        121924      50736      71188          0       9704      23568
-/+ buffers/cache:      17464     104460
Swap:            0          0          0
```

I know it is a bad idea, but I tried adding a swap image on the USB flash drive. That prevented the aforementioned error from occurring, but the device simply froze up.

Comment: About half should be ~256MB for that 512MB device. What is the output of `free`? It is the `-/+ buffers/cache` line that you want.

Comment: Thanks, @wingedsubmariner. I've posted it above. This is a Series 4 device; it only has 128MB of RAM.

Comment: Man, I think that was how much RAM my first Linux desktop had (well before CUPS!). That really does look like an out of memory issue. You could try setting up a swap, at least to test, or you could try turning on memory overcommit (run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`). Note that with overcommit Linux will allow processes to ask for as much memory as they want but will start killing them when it runs out - this is likely to cause system instability.

Comment: thanks @wingedsubmariner, I didn't know about ``overcommit_memory``, that solved my problem with ``CUPS`` in a RPi.